# How do i display multiple MessageDialog with JOptionPane

Tags: java, arraylist, joptionpane

How do I display a message dialog for every char in a string with the `JOptionPane`?
I'm converting the string to char already and storing it in an `ArrayList` but I cannot make 1 char appear for every `JOptionPane`.

Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Character> arr = new ArrayList<Character>();

    String oracion = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Favor Ingrese oracion: ");        

    for(int i=0;i<oracion.length();i++)
    {
        arr.add(oracion.charAt(i));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, arr);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace code

```
arr.add(oracion.charAt(i));
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, arr);
```

with

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, oracion.charAt(i));
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked but how would i be able to use an arraylist in that case ??

Comment: You haven't to use `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < oracion.length(); i++) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, oracion.charAt(i));
}
```

instead of

```
for(int i=0;i<oracion.length();i++)
{
    arr.add(oracion.charAt(i));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, arr);

}
```

and you don't need this line anymore:

```
ArrayList<Character> arr = new ArrayList<Character>();
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked but how would i be able to use an arraylist in that case ??